# Script to Change Registry DWORD

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, registry

I need a script to change the value of a DWORD to 0 in Windows 7 Home Premium in order to prevent Microsoft Security Essentials wizard from deploying after sysprep. I know how to work that with sysprep and just need the script. I've tried a couple vbs and played around but without success.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Security Client

DWORD: OOBE

Change value to 0
```

Please let me know if there is a resource and I can just do this myself. I'm new to scripting and am not intending on burdening stack wizards with dumb questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBS try this test:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite "HKLM\ABC", 0, "REG_DWORD"
```

The result should be:
[image]

Be sure you run the script with elevated rights.

Comment: My results match yours! I edited the script for my path and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell can do this

```c
sp 'hklm:software/microsoft/microsoft security client' OOBE 0 -t dword
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I saved the code as registryfix.reg beginning with "Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00". The file executes successfully but does not change the value. I have changed the 0 to 0x00000000, "0x00000000", "0" in the code. Any suggestions?